# How to pass arguments into class in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, oop, arguments

I'm starting to learn about OOP in Python. I have a simple problem like this: I want to create a class Corner, which represents corners of a polygon. Each corner has (x,y) as its coordinate. Below is my code

```
 class corner():  # Creating class corner and pass x,y as coordinate (updated as guide)

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


#Creating objects from class (still doesn't work)
cornerA=corner(1,2)
print(cornerA) #Expected (1,2)
cornerB=corner(3,4)
print(cornerB) #Expected (3,4)
```

Comment: Please review how classes work in `python`. You need to look up the `__init__()` method.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a structured tutorial: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. That's not how you define a class.

Comment: You've basically written a function and called it a class. If you change `class corner` to `def corner` then your code would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class corner should look like this:

```
class corner():  # Creating class corner and pass x,y as coordinate

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: There is never a need to `return` anything from the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I saw this thing in a video. May I ask if "self" must be in the def function parameter while in a class? When I try to code this in Python it automatically adds "self" in it, maybe it's obligated?

Comment: Returning something other than `None` is not only unnecessary, it is a `TypeError`.

Comment: you will need `self.` to define and call a variable inside a class

Comment: Many methods in classes need a first parameter. The convention is to name it `self`. This is not mandatory, but an extremely strong convention.

Comment: I'm sorry but cornerA=corner(1,2) still doesn't work. When i try to print cornerA it show "<__main__.corner object at 0x0000017F6F61AFB0>" instead of (1,2)

Comment: @QuangHoàngMinh that _does_ work. That's just the default `repr`esentation of the class. If all you actually want is a tuple `(1, 2)` then you don't need the class at all.